# Is there a way to connect volume within different container and docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I have two Docker Host with one container each. For example I have a Container A (Host A) and Container B(Host B), Is there a way that all the volumes or mount inside Container A(Host A) will go straight to Container B(Host B)? I'm using Docker Swarm but I can't figure it out with stack.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly the question, when you have two hosts, you can use a shared drive, live NFS or S3. Then you mount this drive on the two hosts and you can have your volume share in container A and B.

Comment: Instead in Application Container currently inside Host A, I want the filesystem inside container A will be directly on Container B which is for my Database. Is this applicable?